# Is it possible to dynamically change the mutability of a pydantic class?

Tags: python, pydantic

I was thinking about using a pydantic class to support a builder pattern, where the object values are set, one attribute at a time, and then at the end, the object values are frozen.

To that end, is it possible in pydantic to make an object immutable after starting out mutable?

Comment: Not directly the answer to your question, but why not have a `Builder` class that does the building, then have a `build` method returning an immutable object of a second class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class is subclassed from [`BaseModel`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#basic-model-usage), then mutability/immutability is configured by adding a [Model Config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/) inside the class with an `allow_mutation` attribute set to either `True`/`False`.

Sample Code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, NonNegativeInt

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: NonNegativeInt

    class Config:
        allow_mutation = False

p = Person(name='Jack', age=15)
p.name = 'Jill'
```

Sample Output:

```
TypeError: "Person" is immutable and does not support item assignment
```

Now, this `Config` object and `allow_mutation` attribute (or any of the other Model Config attributes) can also be accessed and toggled from methods of the class as:

```py
self.__config__.allow_mutation
```

Sample Code:

```py
class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: NonNegativeInt

    def __init__(self, **data) -> None:
        super().__init__(**data)
        self.__config__.allow_mutation = False

    def is_mutable(self):
        print(self.__config__, self.__config__.allow_mutation)

p = Person(name='Jack', age=15)
p.is_mutable()
p.name = 'Jill'
```

Sample Output:

```
<class '__main__.Config'> False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    p.name = 'Jill'
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 418, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__setattr__
TypeError: "Person" is immutable and does not support item assignment
```

Putting that together, you can make a class initially mutable (`allow_mutation` is `True`), then set its attributes one at a time (directly or via a method), then at the end, call some method to make it immutable (`allow_mutation` is `False`):

Sample Code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, NonNegativeInt

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: NonNegativeInt

    def __init__(self, **data) -> None:
        super().__init__(**data)
        self.__config__.allow_mutation = True

    def build(self):
        self.__config__.allow_mutation = False

print('-- Create a Person --')
p = Person(name='Jack', age=15)
print(p)

print('-- It is initially mutable, can set its attributes --')
p.name = 'Jill'
p.age = 17
print(p)

print('-- Making it immutable --')
p.build()

p.name = 'Jack'
```

Sample Output:

```
-- Create a Person --
name='Jack' age=15
-- It is initially mutable, can set its attributes --
name='Jill' age=17
-- Making it immutable --
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    p.name = 'Jack'
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 418, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__setattr__
TypeError: "Person" is immutable and does not support item assignment
```

Some notes about this:

1. Accessing the private/internal `__config__` object may not be a future-proof solution. If it gets renamed or how the `Config` object is used changes, then this solution breaks. It is also not mentioned in the [ModelConfig](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/) section of the docs, so it's probably not intended to be used like this.
2. Pydantic mentions that this `allow_mutation` is just "*faux immutability*". It basically aborts the `__setattr__` call if `allow_mutation` is False:

   ```py
   # In pydantic/main.py > BaseModel

       elif not self.__config__.allow_mutation or self.__config__.frozen:
           raise TypeError(f'"{self.__class__.__name__}" is immutable and does not support item assignment')
   ```