# How to dynamically change the `alias_generator` Config of Pydantic models during runtime?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to change the `alias_generator` and the `allow_population_by_field_name` properties of the `Config` class of a Pydantic model during runtime. I am expecting it to cascade from the parent model to the child models.

```
class ParentModel(BaseModel):
  class Config:
    alias_generator = to_camel
    allow_population_by_field_name = True

class ChildModel(ParentModel):
  first_name: str

class ChildModel2(ParentModel):
  data: ChildModel
```

What I want to do is to change the following during runtime.

```
alias_generator = to_pascal
```

How would I be able to do that?

I tried something like this:

```
class ParentModel(BaseModel):
  def __init__(self, is_camel = True, **data):
    self.Config.alias_generator = to_camel if is_camel else to_pascal

  class Config:
    allow_population_by_field_name = True

class ChildModel(ParentModel):
  first_name: str

class ChildModel2(ParentModel):
  def __init__(self, is_camel, **data):
    super.__init__(is_camel, **data)

  data: ChildModel


test = ChildModel2(is_camel=False, data=ChildModel(first_name="test"))
```

So the goal is to convert the pydantic models to json in either camel case or pascal case or snake case when the fast api returns the response.

Comment: It is possible to dynamically modify the config options via `self.__config__` (see [example here for dynamically changing `allow_mutation`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67078207/2745495)), but I think **it depends on the config option**. For aliases, Pydantic does some "magic" for aliases and it is dependent on where it's set, see docs on https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#alias-precedence. I am editing this question to focus it specifically on the `alias_generator`.

Comment: Yep, it was a typo. Code is just for reference.

Comment: How do you generate the JSON? Do you use the `.json()` method of a `BaseModel`?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I am guessing fastapi internally uses `.json(by_alias=True)` and generates the json response.